# Show SAPUI5 View two times simultaneous

Tags: sapui5

I build a sapui5 application which shows information related to a SAP plant. Now I need to show the same view two times on the same page but with information of two different plants. Imagine like two iFrames. The App should be able to run with only one view (like now), also it should be able to show data several times on the same page.

To solve this, I build an additional view (splitview) which contains a componentcontainer to load the "real" view (main view). This ends up in a continuous loop.

This is how I tried to build splitview

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    controllerName="zqinsplotlist.zqinsplotlist.controller.splitview" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="Title">
                <content>
                    <l:HorizontalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding">
                        <ComponentContainer xmlns="sap.ui.core" name="zqinsplotlist.zqinsplotlist"
                            settings='\{ "componentData" : \{ "startupParameters" : \{"Werks" : ["1001"], "Zfcod" : ["PLOS"], "Herkunft" : ["03"] \} \}\}'/>
                        <Text text="Hello Split"/>
                    </l:HorizontalLayout>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

I expected that this will load my Main view once. But it gets called in a loop over and over again.

Comment: looks like you're loading component `zqinsplotlist.zqinsplotlist` it in itself `name="zqinsplotlist.zqinsplotlist"`, is that possible? that would cause an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try sth. like this:

```
<mvc:View 
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
  xmlns="sap.m" 
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  controllerName="zqinsplotlist.zqinsplotlist.controller.splitview" 
  xmlns:data="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <App>
    <l:HorizontalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding">
      <mvc:XMLView 
        viewName="zqinsplotlist.zqinsplotlist.view.MyView" 
        data:some="data to distinguish the views" 
        data:instance="1"
      />
      <mvc:XMLView
        viewName="zqinsplotlist.zqinsplotlist.view.MyView" 
        data:some="other data to distinguish this view from the above" 
      />              
    </l:HorizontalLayout>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

In the controller of MyView distinguish the two view instances by sth. like this:

```
if (this.getView().data('instance') === 1) {
  // do stuff
}
```

That should work but I haven't tested. Not a 100% sure that custom data works on views instanciated from XML. Well, it should...

BR
Chris